# How to detect home button press in android launcher?

Tags: android, launcher

I am making a launcher for android os. But I dont know how to detect home button pressed when launcher app is working? Thanks you!

This is config in Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/NoActiobarTheme"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Comment: I found a video tutorial series will teach you from A to Z about launcher https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tml0oqLyY78&list=PLxabZQCAe5fhGgSue40-_DjfFc_5EThhr

Comment: I would expect that your running `MainActivity` will be called with `onNewIntent()`.

Comment: Yes, by use onNewIntent() and it has working. Thanks you!